# Corrupt member variable in derived class with Curiously Recurring Templating Pattern

Tags: c++, polymorphism, crtp

I'm currently playing around with CRTP and am coming across the issue of a member variable in the derived class being corrupted aka having a garbage value (there are currently 4 levels of polymorphism, with the top most base class called "A" and the bottom most derived class called "D").

Here is some code that displays an example of this issue:

```
//A.hpp
template <class TB>
class A {
public:
    A();
    void CRTP_func();
};

template <class TB>
A<TB>::A() {
    std::cout << "A constructor called!" << std::endl;
}

template<class TB>
void A<TB>::CRTP_func() {
    std::cout << "CRTP_index called in A" << std::endl;
    static_cast<TB*>(this)->CRTP_func2();
}

//B.hpp
#include "A.hpp"
#include <vector>

template<class TC>
class B : public A<B<TC>>
{
public:
    B();
    void CRTP_func2();
};

template<class TC>
B<TC>::B() {
    std::cout << "B constructor called!" << std::endl;
}

template<class TC>
void B<TC>::CRTP_func2() {
    std::cout << "CRTP_func called in B" << std::endl;
    static_cast<TC*>(this)->CRTP_func3();
}

//C.hpp
#include "B.hpp"

template<class TD>
class C : B<C<TD>> {
public:
    C();
    void CRTP_func3();
    int x;
};

template<class TD>
C<TD>::C() {
    std::cout << "C constructor called" << std::endl;
}

template<class TD>
void C<TD>::CRTP_func3() {
    std::cout << "CRTP_index3 called in C" << std::endl;
    static_cast<TD*>(this)->CRTP_func4();
}


//D.hpp
#include "C.hpp"

    class D : C<D> {
    public:
        D();
        bool onInit();
        void CRTP_func4();
        C<D> top;
        int y = 0;

    };

D::D() {
    std::cout << "D constructor called!" << std::endl;
}

bool D::onInit() {
    std::cout << "D onInit called!" << std::endl;
    y = 5;
    return true;
}

void D::CRTP_func4() {
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "CRTP_index4 called in D! " << std::endl;
}

//main.hpp
int main {
D * D_ptr = new D();
    D_ptr->onInit();
    D_ptr->top.CRTP_func3();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see A is the base class while D is the derived class as such:

```
A<B<C<D>>>
```

The output for this program is as follows:

```
A constructor called!
B constructor called!
C constructor called
A constructor called!
B constructor called!
C constructor called
D constructor called!
D onInit called!
CRTP_index3 called in C
-33686019
CRTP_index4 called in D!
```

The value -33686019 is printed out in D.hpp where the value y is printed and is set to 5 upon initialization. After a little digging I checked the value in main.cpp and it is set to 5 even after making these CRTP calls, yet a garbage value gets printed.

After some more debugging I realized that removing the line

```
int x;
```

in B.hpp solves this problem, so I think the issue has to do with some misalignment, but I am not sure why this would happen. Does anyone know why this would happen or how to fix it?

Sorry for the long post and ambiguous code, I tried to remove most of the complexity and simplify the code as much as possible for the sake of the post.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the comments below I figured out how to fix my issue. Instead of using `D::top`, a better approach is to create a pointer in the main file as such:

`C<D> * C_ptr = static_cast<C<D>*>(D_ptr);`

and then call `CRTP_func3()` from there as such:

`C_ptr->CRTP_func3();`

This works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the function `CRTP_func3()` on an object with static type `C<D>` (`D::top`). The function `C<D>::CRTP_func3()` does a `static_cast<D*>(this)` but the object doesn't have the expected type. Thus, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I may have a flaw in my understanding of how CRTP works, but I would think that the expected type of the object is D, therefore '`static_cast<D*>(this)` would make sense to me. Since this is not the case, what is the expected type of the object?

Comment: @lockdown: the member is declared as `C<D> top;` Why would that object change the type to become `D`? Just because you also have class `D` which derives from `C<D>` the type of all `C<D>` object doesn't change.

Comment: Thank you! I just now realized where I was going wrong. A better approach would be to use `C<D> * C_ptr = static_cast<C<D>*>(D_ptr);` instead of using `D::top`.

Answer (score 0):

The most fundamental problem you have, logic-wise, is that you are expecting `D_Ptr` and `D_Ptr->top` to have the same value for `y`  (you said you expected 5).  `D_Ptr->top` is an entirely different instance and even if it ultimately derived from `D`, would have its own copy of `y`.

Then, `D` derives from `C`, so it's fundamentally impossible for a `C` to derive from `D`, regardless of template insanity.  That's the assumption you make by calling `CRTP_func4` on a `this` pointer of C.

Furthermore, that same function call assumes the template type `TD` is an instance of `D`.  That function call exists within `C`, and that's an insane assumption for `C` to make--although I believe it happens to be correct in this case.  (*that* one the compiler would catch if it weren't)

Lastly regarding crtp: consider rejecting Satan and all his ways.

But seriously, there's obviously no complete stand-in, but I think you'll find if you fully consider the power of interfaces (or `pure abstract classes` in C++), you *may* be able to find a way around using it.  And have (nearly) the same performance...  I don't know your specific problem, of course, but I'd highly recommend taking a long, careful look at this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Particularly look at the 2nd example code block, that's written in C# (where `interface` would be a `pure abstract class` in C++).  Give some thought to whether this pattern could help you.

Comment: You are right! I was creating a new instance of `D` by creating a new instance of `C<D>`, therefor the values of y would obviously be different. Thank you so much for your help! As for CRTP, I'm using it as it is significantly quicker than virtual functions and speed is of utmost importance for my project.

Comment: @lockdown - Edited my answer.  I hope it's helpful.